# swagger-codegen: how do I retrieve tag description?

Tags: swagger

In my swagger file I have defined a list of tags as follows:

```
"tags": [
    { "name": "TagA", "description": "DescriptionA" },
    { "name": "TagB", "description": "DescriptionB" }
]
```

When I generate client code using swagger-codegen (2.1.2-M1), all operations marked with a certain tag become methods in a class named after the tag, e.g. "class TagBApi". Is there any way to retrieve the tag description and output it as a comment in the class? I haven't seen any examples of this in the available .mustache files. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

there is no support for the tag descriptions in the codegen--please [open an issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues) and it can be added.